# Aggregate stacked hourly raster data into six hour layers

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have a large raster stack of sea surface temp raster layers (one for each hour) over a long period, however I want to find the average of these layers for six hour periods 00:00 - 0600, 0600 - 1200, 1200 - 1800, and 1800 - 2400).

Example of current names:

```
names(sstrasters)
   [1] "X2021.01.31.00" "X2021.01.31.01" "X2021.01.31.02" "X2021.01.31.03" "X2021.01.31.04" "X2021.01.31.05" "X2021.01.31.06"
   [8] "X2021.01.31.07" "X2021.01.31.08" "X2021.01.31.09" "X2021.01.31.10" "X2021.01.31.11" "X2021.01.31.12" "X2021.01.31.13"
  [15] "X2021.01.31.14" "X2021.01.31.15" "X2021.01.31.16" "X2021.01.31.17" "X2021.01.31.18" "X2021.01.31.19" "X2021.01.31.20"
  [22] "X2021.01.31.21" "X2021.01.31.22" "X2021.01.31.23" "X2021.02.01.00" "X2021.02.01.01" "X2021.02.01.02" "X2021.02.01.03"
  [29] "X2021.02.01.04" "X2021.02.01.05" "X2021.02.01.06" "X2021.02.01.07" "X2021.02.01.08" "X2021.02.01.09" "X2021.02.01.10"
  [36] "X2021.02.01.11" "X2021.02.01.12" "X2021.02.01.13" "X2021.02.01.14" "X2021.02.01.15" "X2021.02.01.16" "X2021.02.01.17"
```

I then want to create a new raster stack with just these averaged layers, named like this (based on the final hour):

```
2021 01 31: 0000 - 0600 = "X2021.01.31.06" 
2021 01 31: 0600 - 1200 = "X2021.01.31.12" 
2021 01 31: 1200 - 1800 = "X2021.01.31.18"
2021 01 31: 1800 - 2400 = "X2021.01.31.00"
```

I tried to use indices but am a bit confused on how these work, the stack does not contain the final full day so is not divisible by 6.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. For the future, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it will be easier to help you.

```
library(terra)

#create an hourly sequence for 1 year
namer <- seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 01:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-12-31 24:00:00"), by="hour")
#create example data with 1 layer for each hour
r <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = rnorm(100),nlyrs=length(namer),time=namer)
#create indexes for aggregation
index <- rep(1:(length(namer)/6),each=6)
#aggregate with tapp
sixhourly <- tapp(r,index,fun=mean)
time(sixhourly) <- namer[seq(6,length(name),6)]
```

The idea is to split the raster into blocks of 6 layers (one for each hour) and compute the mean. The function `tapp` in the `terra` package is designed precisely for this purpose. See `?tapp` for more detail, but it applies the same concept of `base::tapply()`.
To assign the names to the final raster, I indexed the names I'm interested in. However, since we are dealing with times, the best option here is to assign the final time to the time slot of the `rast` object with the function `terra::time()<-` (if you prefer to assign the time info as a name, use `names(sixhourly)<-namer[seq(6,length(name),6)])`